# easiest framework for a simple 2D animation

Tags: java, animation, 2d

Well I am going to bed right now, and in next 2 days I have to code a simple program with animation that will simulate an **inverted broom on a cart** (a *pole balancing* genetic algorithm problem) the cart has to be pushed constantly from both sides to prevent the broom from falling down

You can see it in this video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ums3eGIVgks
or this picture [image http://lis.epfl.ch/research/projects/EvolutionOfAnalogNetworks/ArtificialNeuralNetworks/images/mechanik_small.png](http://lis.epfl.ch/research/projects/EvolutionOfAnalogNetworks/ArtificialNeuralNetworks/images/mechanik_small.png)

Well, I need to simulate physical behavior of this, but I have very little time, so I need something that I can understand and start using fast (the assignment is more into physics and genetic programming, so the simulation has to be just to show how it works).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'd use HTML5 Canvas and pure javascript.  It's super easy, you don't need to compile.  All you need is notepad, Chrome/Firefox/IE9, and a little time.  There are tons of examples out there:

http://3.paulhamill.com/node/36

Answer (score 0):

If you want an application, create a java application which uses a JPanel in a JFrame. In the JPanel override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, and look at the graphics class which allows you to draw simple shapes like lines, rectangles, and ellipses.

Comment: How about gravitation in JPanel? I dont think that would simplify my issue.